# Cant get js slide to expand to fit more content

Tags: javascript

My client has contacted me 2 years after building their site:
http://www.broomedaycare.com/reviews.html#4

to add more testimonials to this script.

The site is using slides.min.jquery.js" and "hoverIntent.js".

One of the new testimonials is quite long and would not fit in the previously designed allocated space. I uploaded a new background that was higher to cater for the additional text and gave the testimonial div and then the class "headline" more height and tried changing the values in the script and have generally been mucking around with it for over an hour trying to get it to work!

Now I have set everything back to the way it was except for I have added the extra testimonials in the html.

I would really appreciate some-one who knows javascript to have a look at this for me. Thanks a zillion!

Comment: Have you tried using this http://trentwalton.com/2011/05/10/fit-to-scale/ where you can fit the text to your container?

Comment: Sorry if this is obtuse, but why not just ask the client if you can edit the testimonial down to a size that fits in the window?

Comment: Hi thanks for your responses.  Fit to scale is not a slider and is more for headlines and responsive websites and asking my client to reduce her testimonials seems a bit unprofessional but if worse comes to worse and I cant work out how to do it, then I guess I will have to! PS fit to scale is pretty awesome, thanks for sharing!